# Running remote windows GUI application through ssh

Tags: python, ssh, pytest

I'm using py.test to run a series of python scripts that test an external windows GUI application.

I'm trying to run these tests on a remote ssh-enabled windows machines using fabric (using Bitvise SSH server on the remote end) but of course the tests which require GUI access fail.

I know that py.test has a package called xdist, but I guess it will suffer from the same problem if the channel we use is SSH.

Has anybody solved the issue of running remote GUI applications in Windows through SSH? SSH has been quite convenient for me to run remote deployment commands, and it would logically follow that py.test would be one of such commands.

Comment: Did you try to run commands with ssh as a user that is logged on a screen?

Comment: I run my commands as a user who has administrator rights. The problem is that the shell doesn't give access to the windows GUI